# Second order Runge Kutta method for solving second-order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Earlier I used to euler method to solve 2nd order ODE in a dyanimc which didn't result in a good accuracy. Can someone provide me with the psuedocode/method to solve 2nd order ODE using rk2. Please provide an example to help understand better if possibe.
 Equations of motion I am trying to solve:

\begin{equation}
 \frac{dx}{dt} = v 
 \end{equation}
 \begin{equation}
 m .\frac{dv}{dt}= f_{1}(x)+f_{2}(x,v)
 \end{equation}

Limits: [$x_{0}$ $h$ $x^{'}$]

Comment: There are few links, on the but there is not much lucidness in terms of solved example showing 2 order ODE

Comment: @Amzoti I have used rk4 already, but it is very slow due to the computational time of $f_1$ and $f_2$ being quite high. How would about the error in terms solving using rk2 and euler. In rk4 there is a sure great reduction. (https://dafeda.wordpress.com/2011/03/27/comparison-of-ode-solvers-rk4-ode45-euler/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the midpoint method:

$$s_{x1}=h f_x (t_i, v_i)$$

$$s_{v1}=h f_v (t_i, x_i, v_i)$$

$$s_{x2}=h f_x(t_i+\frac{1}{2} h, v_i+\frac{1}{2}s_{v1})$$

$$s_{v2}=h f_v(t_i+\frac{1}{2}h, x_i+\frac{1}{2}s_{x1}, v_i +\frac{1}{2} s_{v1})$$
$$x_{i+1}=x_i+s_{x2}$$
$$v_{i+1}=v_{i}+s_{v2}$$

where $f_x(t,x,v)=v$ and $f_v(t,x,v)=\frac{1}{m}(f_1(x)+f_2(x,v))$.

The method has order $2$, should be better than Euler's method.

Comment: Thanks! Can you check the subscripts of f in the first two equations once again, I think there is something mistyped.

Comment: I didn't find any typo. Which one do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I edited!

Comment: you added only sx2  not sx1. Can you mention reason?

Comment: That's the rule of midpoint method. Notice that $s_{x2}$ includes $s_{x1}$ in its definition. It is $h$ times the derivative of the midpoint.